# Determining what users have two-factor authentication turned on for SoftLayer Portal

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have been asked to determine if everyone in the SoftLayer tenancies I am apart of has turned on two-factor authentication to the portal.

Is there a way using the SoftLayer APIs to determine this?
If so, what are the required calls?
and, does it need to be performed by the master user or what privileges do I require?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see who has or not two-factor you can use the method [SoftLayer_Account::getUsers](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers) with a object-mask, this method retrieve portal users in the account and you need to have at least Basic User privileges.

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers?objectMask=mask[id,username,firstName,lastName,externalBindingCount,externalBindings]
```

Users without two-factor has **externalBindingCount = 0** and for other users you should be able to see if it is active or not through the property **active**.

Now if you want to know who has two-factor and it is active/inactive specifically, you need to use following filter (1 is true and 0 is false):

```
objectFilter={"users":{"externalBindings":{"active":{"operation":"1"}}}}
```

Next is the complete REST request.

```
https://[userName]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getUsers?objectMask=mask[id,username,firstName,lastName,externalBindingCount,externalBindings]&objectFilter={"users":{"externalBindings":{"active":{"operation":"1"}}}}
```